# Excel counting pattern every 5th rows

Tags: excel, formula, editing

So, I have this 120k rows in excel with format.

```
id number description
1    1     apple
2    1     banana
3    1     pineapple
4    1     b
5    1     c
6    6     d
7    6     e
8    6     f
9    6     g
10   6     e
```

what formula can I use in the number column so that it will be the same as the table above? every 5th rows I will change the number of number column based on number on the 6th row of id column. Note that number column is blank right now.

Comment: Your title doesn't make sense. Are you just trying to display `1` fives times, then `6` five times, etc?

Comment: I edited the title and description. Hope it more understandable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Enigmativity's solution gives you the desired result, the results will vary by the row from where you start your column. Here is how i would recommend to do it.

Enter 1 in the first cell you want to start the pattern from (`B2` in my case) .
in the next cell(`B3`) enter

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW($B$2),5)=0,B2+5,B2)
```

and copy the formula down. This should give you the desired pattern as long as you update the starting cell address (`B2` and `$B$2`)

Comment: Amazing, you saved me a lot of headache on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 =5*INT((ROW(RC)-1)/5)+1
```

I get:

```
1
1
1
1
1
6
6
6
6
6
11
11
11
11
11
16
16
```

I used R1C1 notation, but just replace the `RC` with the current cell (i.e. `B2`) if you're using `A1` mode.