# Increase the value for Excel sheet Column value for every 5 cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, auto-increment

In Excel Sheet how can i Increase the value for Excel sheet Column value for every 5 cells

i want to give values in a Column

```
Sno testno
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1   
6   2
7   2
8   2
9   2
10  2
11  3
12  3
13  3
14  3
15  3
16  4
17  4
```

For Every 5 values the value will increase.
Any Forumla can do this for me.? or manually i have to Change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel counting pattern every 5th rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43750141/excel-counting-pattern-every-5th-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter this formula: `=INT((ROW(E1)-1)/5)+1` into a blank cell where you want to fill the sequential numbers,

see screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
B2:
=1+INT((A2-1)/5)
```

copy and paste down in column B.

p.s. you could use `=1+INT((ROW()-2)/5)` but if you had already generated the column A like this, it's better to use the first form because you can then move your table anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

from A1 to A5 type in 1.In cell A6 type in formula as =a1+1 and drag down the formula till you wish for. It should work out.